# webcam not working "showing device not Found" (Recently installed ubuntu 18.04 )

Tags: 18.04, dell, webcam, system, ubuntu-drivers

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. While operating through cheese application webcam is still not working.

[image: the screenshot] [image: the screenshot]

I tried to find the solutions through the forum but doesn't worked for me. My laptop specifications are Dell Inspiron 3542 core i7. I haven't found anything related to Dell laptops solutions for this issue.

Comment: `getfacl /dev/video0` Search in bios/uefi if something relevant to the camera.  Notebooks often have a shortcut for enable or disable some device.

Comment: i have already check for the shortcut key but its not there .@nobody

Comment: Please show `lsusb` and `getfacl /dev/video0` edit your question for that.

Comment: can you give the commands for the lsusb and getfacl /dev/video0.@nobody

Comment: that were the commands. Open  terminal and cp&paste `lsusb` wair for output, and afterward   `getfacl /dev/video0`

Comment: please have look @nobody

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont see any camera.

Comment: that's the problem @nobody